# Changing a class's base class for unit testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pytest, metaprogramming

I've got a class I'm trying to test.  It inherits from a base class which has some functionality which is both inconvenient and irrelevant to the testing so I'm trying to replace it for the purpose of the unit test.

I've got this far:

```
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

import types
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def uut():
    global Bar
    old_bar = Bar
    Bar = types.new_class(Bar.__name__, (object,), {}, lambda ns: ns.update(Bar.__dict__))
    try:
        yield Bar
    finally:
        Bar = old_bar

def test_Bar(uut):
    b = uut()
```

This fails with:

```
FAILED test.py::test_Bar - TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

AFAICT this is now `types.new_class()` is intended to be used.  What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried using `mock.Mock` as a baseclass and adding `"metaclass": type` to the (currently-empty) keywords parameter but neither of these seems to change anything.

Comment: Move both `import` to top, not anywhere.

Comment: @toyotaSupra - you put the imports for your tests in the code for the unit under test???  Obviously in practice these would be two separate files and this is the minimal reproducible example.  I thought that went without saying but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you hit is subtle, and is of one many edge cases you are subject to be hit with by trying this.

This is what is happening. In this line:

```
Bar = types.new_class(Bar.__name__, (object,), {}, lambda ns: ns.update(Bar.__dict__))
```

you create a new class named "Bar" ok, but with the `__init__` method as is in the original `Bar`: that `__init__` when using `super()`  will look for the superclass of that `Bar`: that will happen either with the parameterless version of `super()` (it uses a "hidden" `__class__` variable which refers to the original `Bar`), but will just happen the same if you use the explicit, Python-2 like version (`super(Bar, self)`).

One attempt could be to *actually* modify the `Bar` class for the duration of the test, os that its bases are only `(object,)`. That is not guaranteed to work, and can certainly cause problems if other parts of the test would instantiate the original class - it just won't behave as expected.

That said, you can try this:

```
...

class FakeBase: pass

@pytest.fixture
def uut():

    old_bases = Bar.__bases__
    
    try:
        Bar.__bases__ = (FakeBase,)  # modifies the original class inplace
        yield Bar
    finally:
        Bar.__bases__ = old_bases
```

on a side note, you should not play around with the global name `Bar` like you do - if the class can't be passed as fixture, and therefore as an argument, to wherever it will be used, you can use `unittest.mock.patch` (or pytest's extensions equivalent. Anyway, for the code I posted above, no need to worry, as the class is modified in place for the duration of the test.

This code will fail if `Foo`, your original base is special in some sense: if it inherits from a built-in class other than object, or has `__slots__`, or something - in each case, you have to modify  `FakeBase` so that it has the same attributes as the original `Foo` base.